Fastify ACL PreHandle Middleware Question
I am trying to create a custom ACL middleware in fastify, there is 3 files here I am giving:
authMiddleware.mjs:
import {validateToken} from "../repository/authRepository.mjs";
import {PrismaClient} from "@prisma/client";

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

// Middleware to check if the user is authenticated
export async function authMiddleware(request, response) {
    const token = request.headers['authorization']?.split(' ')[1];
    if (!token) {
        return response.code(401).send({message: "Unauthorized"});
    }
    const decodedUser = validateToken(request.server, token);
    if (decodedUser) {
        // Get latest user data from database
        const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
            where: {
                id: decodedUser.id
            },
            include: {
                role: true
            },
        })
        if (user) {
            if (user.accountStatus !== "ACTIVE") {
                return response.code(401).send({message: "User is not active"});
            }
            // Check if there's an active token for the user
            const userToken = await prisma.userToken.findFirst({
                where: {
                    userId: user.id,
                    userToken: token,
                },
            });
            if (userToken) {
                const currentTime = Date.now();
                const tokenExpiryTime = userToken.expireAt.getTime();

                if (currentTime > tokenExpiryTime) {
                    return response.code(401).send({message: "Token expired"});
                }

                // Update the user's IP address with the latest one
                await prisma.userToken.update({
                    where: {
                        id: userToken.id,
                    },
                    data: {
                        ipAddress: request.ip,
                    },
                });
                request.user = {
                    userId: user.id,
                    userRole: user.role.title,
                    firstName: user.firstName,
                    lastName: user.lastName,
                    emailAddress: user.emailAddress
                };
            } else {
                return response.code(401).send({message: "Invalid or expired token"});

            }
        } else {
            return response.code(401).send({message: "Invalid or expired token"});

        }
    } else {
        return response.code(401).send({message: "Invalid or expired token"});
    }
}

aclMiddleware.mjs:
// ACL Middleware
export async function aclMiddleware(request, response) {
    const allowedRoles = ["Administrator"];
    const hasAccess = allowedRoles.includes(request.user?.userRole);
    if (!hasAccess) {
        return response.code(403).send({error: 'Access Denied'});
    }
}

brandRoute.mjs:
import {defaultStatusCodeResponses} from "../routes/routeSchema.mjs";
import {authMiddleware} from "../middleware/authMiddleware.mjs";
import {aclMiddleware} from "../middleware/aclMiddleware.mjs";

/** @type {import('fastify').FastifyPluginAsync<> } */
export default async function (app) {
    app.get('/brands', {
            preHandler: [authMiddleware, aclMiddleware],
            schema: {
                description: "Get All Brands API",
                tags: ["Brand"],
                summary: "Get All Brands",
                security: [{bearerAuth: []}],
                querystring: {
                    type: "object",
                    properties: {
                        page: {type: "number", minimum: 1, default: 1},
                        size: {type: "number", minimum: 5, default: 5},
                        keywords: {type: "string"},
                    },
                    required: ["page", "size"]
                },
            }
        }, async (request, response) => {
            return {brands: []};
        }
    );
}

Here I do have 2 question:

as in async pre handler I can not use next() aka done() param that is the reason i have to use 3 separate return 401, can this be overcome like if success pass to next middleware and in the last write code something like this:
return next();
}
}
}
return response.code(401).send({message: "Invalid or expired token"});

I am using an static array of roles that is accepted over aclMiddleware, is there a way to send that array from the route itself like:
preHandler: [authMiddleware, aclMiddleware(['Administrator'])]


Thanks everyone in advance....

Referring to your second question, you can pass the roles array as a parameter to the aclMiddleware by refactor to be factory function that returns a middleware. See general code example below:
export function aclMiddleware(allowedRoles) {
    return async function (request, response) {
        const hasAccess = allowedRoles.includes(request.user?.userRole);
        if (!hasAccess) {
           return response.code(403).send({error: 'Access Denied'});
        }
    }
}

And now you can send an array of allowed rules in the preHandler hook:
preHandler: [authMiddleware, aclMiddleware(['Administrator'])]

As for the first question, there's no need for all the else statements - you can leave a single return at the end of your middleware that will be executed when ever authorization fails
